# What is ActionId in the log entry when using serilog in ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, seq

So looking at the logs created by serilog I see `ActionId` value that is some type of GUID. I know this is added by ASP.NET Core app by default but what exactly is this value?

One example of log entry contains following entries (among others):

```
ActionId: 1fbc88fa-42db-424f-b32b-c2d0994463f1
ActionName: /Index
```

I notice that `ActionId` can be different for the same `ActionName` but what exactly it represents? And for what good use can `ActionId` be used when I am searching through my logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just simply unique [ActionDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that asp.net core generate for your app.

I'm not so sure why are you curious at this... but [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/MvcCoreLoggerExtensions.cs#L1643) prove what's i'm saying.

> I notice that `ActionId` can be different for the same `ActionName`

`ActionId` will survive the whole application life-time, but when you re-deploy the app, the `ActionDescriptor` got initialized. Therefore, difference Id.

> And for what good use can `ActionId` be used when I am searching through my logs

Clearly a better way to search your log, like when using elastic, `fields.ActionId: "YourActionIdHere"` will give you all the request that touch the Action method.

Of course, the moment you saw difference `ActionId`, means your app got re-deployed. But actually... I've never using that, since we got plan what and when the app will release.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. The reason I am curious about it is because it is added to the logs by default in APS.NET Core applications, but I couldn't find much info about it especially why it can be different.